# How can I use arrays for multiple buttons

Tags: vb.net

I have 25 buttons, and when I click the button, It will disable itself and give you points. However, I am not really sure how to use an array to prevent repeating the same block of code for all 25 buttons. I tried this but I get errors in the output.

Line 4: Expression expected
Line 6: End of statement expected
Line 9: Expression does not produce a value.

```
Public Class SBCL

Dim number = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
Dim score = As Integer

Private Sub Button(number)_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
score = score + 1
    MsgBox(score & " " & "points out of 25")
    Button(number).Enabled = False
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 4
End Sub

Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    MsgBox("Created by Nathen35 of Moonboy Development.")
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeLogToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeLogToolStripMenuItem.Click
    MsgBox("Version 0.4a: Exit button added. Progress bar added.")
End Sub

Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: hook them up to the same handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this part:

```
Public Class SBCL

    Dim score As Integer

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim button = TryCast(sender, Button)
        If button Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        score = score + 1
        MsgBox(score & " points out of 25")
        button.Enabled = False
        ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 4
    End Sub
```

Then in the Form designer select all 25 buttons > right-click them > `Properties` > `Events` > and in the `Click` event drop-down select the `Button_Click`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hook up the buttons to call the same function. Then in that function you can check what button was clicked and do what you want to do.

```
 Private Sub OnButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click, btn2.Click, btn1.Click
    Dim ClickButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Select Case ClickButton.Name
        Case "btn1"
            'Your Code For btn1 (For your case amount of points to give)
        Case "btn2"
              'Your Code For btn2 (For your case amount of points to give)
        Case "btn3"
            'Your Code For btn3 (For your case amount of points to give)
    End Select
    ClickButton.Enabled = False 'Disable the button after clicking it
End Sub
```

If you are generating the button in the code (and not in the designer) you can use this code:

```
 Private Sub GenerateButtons()
    Dim btn1 As New Button() 'Generates a button
    btn1.Name = "btn1" 'Name of the button
    btn1.Text = "Click me" 'Text on the button
    btn1.Location = New Point(0, 0) 'location of the button
    btn1.Size = New Size(100, 100) 'Size of the button
    Me.Controls.Add(btn1) 'Add the button to the current form
    AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf OnButtonClick 'Bing a click event

    Dim btn2 As New Button()
    btn2.Name = "btn1"
    btn2.Text = "Click me"
    btn2.Location = New Point(200, 200)
    btn2.Size = New Size(100, 100)
    Me.Controls.Add(btn2)
    AddHandler btn2.Click, AddressOf OnButtonClick
End Sub
Private Sub OnButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ClickButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Select Case ClickButton.Name
        Case "btn1"
            'Your Code For btn1 (For your case amount of points to give)
        Case "btn2"
            'Your Code For btn2 (For your case amount of points to give)
    End Select
    ClickButton.Enabled = False 'Disable the button after clicking it
End Sub
```