# Labels' Click events

Tags: vb.net, label

I have an application where I have around 50 labels. In those labels a number is visible.
When the user clicks on the label the number needs to be written to an edit box.
This works fine, the only problem is that I have added 50 functions like below, and every time it’s the same. I was wondering if there is a common function for this
Remark: The labels have different names. So if its possible that this will work for all the labels on the form.

```
Private Sub LI_L_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LI_L.Click
    cmbOBJID.Text = LI_L.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the labels have anything in common to distinguish them from other labels, for example they are all in a groupbox?

Comment: If they all write to the same place, you can simplify this code by listing all the labels as . . . Handles LI_L.Click, LI_M.click, . . . . and so on. Then replace the specific label with sender.text

Comment: check this article [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540618/how-can-i-use-arrays-for-multiple-buttons/39541958#39541958

Comment: Use object orientation. Derive a class from `Label` and place your handling code there. Then, instead of using the `System.Windows.Forms.Label` control, use your custom control on forms as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the form designer, you should be able to set the handler for every label to the same function. Then you can use the "sender" parameter to determine which label is raising the event.

[image]

Notice also how all the controls that the function is linked to are listed after the "Handles" keyword. This is another way you could connect the code to all the labels if you prefer this over using the Visual Studio UI properties grid.

```
Private Sub LI_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click
    cmdOBJID.Text = DirectCast(sender, Label).Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is easy to add several events to one handler in the style of

```
Private Sub LI_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click
```

It will be tedious for more than just a few labels.

You can add handlers programatically if you can find a way to refer to the labels you need to add handlers to. In this example, I put all the labels in a groupbox named "GroupBoxOptions":

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Sub TransferDataToEditBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim lbl = DirectCast(sender, Label)
        tbEditThis.Text = lbl.Text

    End Sub

    Sub InitLabelHandlers()
        For Each lbl In GroupBoxOptions.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
            AddHandler lbl.Click, AddressOf TransferDataToEditBox
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitLabelHandlers()

    End Sub

End Class
```

You may have some other way of selecting the labels which use the handler.

Comment: **Don't forget to RemoveHandlers**, it is important if you are adding them you need to remove them as well...

Comment: @Zaggler For the case of managed controls like labels, it does not matter.

Comment: It is not as simple as "managed controls". The critical question is whether your event handler is attached to an object that will have a longer lifetime than its container. If so, you need to manually remove the handlers. Otherwise, the event handlers will be automatically removed when the object's container is destroyed. I figure that's probably what you meant by "managed controls", but it's good to be explicit.

Comment: It does matter, managed or not. The object which publishes the events and keeps the targets of the event handlers living is the difference. The label is eligible for garbage collection if nothing else is using it, but the subscririon to TransferDataToTextbox isn't long lived and does ***not know*** about the publisher (the label) and when that is the case you have to unsubscribe the event.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty nice and quick solution is to traverse all the label controls on a form, assigning through the AddHandler function the event to run when a user clicks a label.

In code:

```
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf myLabelClick
    Next
```

With the prevous snippet, we loop onto all the winform controls of type Label. A loop like that is useful when we have a lot of labels for which an event must be assigned. For each of them, we associate the event Click of the control with a customized Sub named myLabelClick. That subroutine will look like the following:

```
Private Sub myLabelClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    cmdObjId.Text = DirectCast(sender, Label).Text
End Sub
```

Here we use the sender variable (which represents the control for which the click has been done) to access its Text property, and change the cmdObjId.Text accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the solution from BlueMonkMN:
If you are using the DevExpress Tools, you need to import DevExpress.XtraEditors and change Label to LabelControl:
`DirectCast(sender, LabelControl).Text`

This worked for me.